# Iphone HTTP Call With ASIHTTPRequest and HotUkDeals

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, asihttprequest

Anyone shed any light on this, im calling the HotUkDeals API from the iphone simulator using a url that I've tested in a browser http://api.hotukdeals.com/rest_api/v2/?key=MYKEY, and in the browser I get a nice XML response, while on the Iphone Simulator I'm getting a HUKD page not found. I've tried Last.fm rest api to test I wasn't making a stupid mistake and I get what I expect. Are iphones being blocked from directly calling the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It due to the useragent, using the iphone simulator the application was being redirected around to the mobile site.

Answer (score 0):

Add `dforward=true` to your GET parameters ;-)